# Cannot read property 'trustAsResourceUrl' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, function, rss, undefined

Having some trouble here. I am creating a news ticker but I keep getting this error
[Cannot read property 'trustAsResourceUrl' of undefined.

Any suggestions as to why?
Sorry can't give you the url(work related reason).

```
ticker.controller("tickerCtrl", [ 'FeedService', '$sce',function ($scope, $sce) {
    this.app = $scope && $scope.$parent && $scope.$parent.app;
    let ticker = this;

    ticker.trustSrc = function (src, $sce) {
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
    }

    $scope.parseFeed('https://www.url.com/rss/all').then(function (res) {
        ticker.items = res.items
    });
    
    setInterval(function () {
        document.getElementById("container-ticker").contentWindow.location.reload()
    },300); 

}]);

ticker.factory('FeedService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    
    return {
        parseFeed: function (url) {
            return $http.jsonp('//api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&rss_url=' + encodeURIComponent((url)).then(function (res) {
                return res.data;
            })
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: The injection parameters don't match in the `tickerCtrl` definition.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am not quite sure what you mean. Are you referring to the dependencies and the parameters injected in the controllers function?

Comment: `[ 'FeedService', '$sce',function ($scope, $sce) {` is wrong.

Comment: Ok I matched the parameters to the definition but I still receive the same error

Answer (score 0):

Your injections need to match inside the array and in the function parameters.

```
// your code
ticker.controller("tickerCtrl", [ 'FeedService', '$sce',function ($scope, $sce)
```

FeedService would match up with $scope because they are the first items injected. That is incorrect. You need to match word for word, in order, otherwise the injection will be improperly mapped.

```
// change to this
ticker.controller("tickerCtrl", [ 'FeedService', '$sce', ‘$scope’, function (FeedService, $sce, $scope)
```

Secondly you shouldn’t be passing $sce into your ticker function. It’s already in your controller.

```
// your code, remove $sce in your params 
ticker.trustSrc = function (src, $sce) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
}
```

Should be

```
ticker.trustSrc = function (src) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
}
```

Comment: As a bonus, I use ng-annotate to automatically handle my injection. You just set the parameters in the function and run the build. Saves a lot of headache. https://github.com/Kagami/gulp-ng-annotate